# C program for infix to postfix expression

Tags: c

There is a run time error. Just asks me for an input and then ends the program. I know it enters the convert loop, I printed somethings for debugging, but nothing I do seems to be working. I don't understand what the problem is because I've compared it to codes online, it should work. The code uses two priority check, one for in stack and one for comparing the stack operators to the infix ones.

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define size 50
struct Stack
{
    char A[size];
    int top=1;
};
typedef struct Stack ShuvStack;

void push(ShuvStack *s, char x)
{
    s->A[s->top]=x;
    s->top=s->top+1;
    

}
char pop(ShuvStack *s){
    char x;
    x=s->A[s->top];
    s->top=s->top-1;
    return(x);
}
int inStckPri(char input)
{
    switch (input) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '(':
            return 0;
    }
}

int inComePri(char input)
{
    switch (input) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '(':
            return 3;
    }
}
int isOperand(char c)
{
    if(c>='a' && c<='z')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}


void convert(char* infix)
{
    char *postfix;
    ShuvStack s;
    char x;
    int i=0,j=0;
    int len=strlen(infix);
    postfix=(char *)malloc((len+2)*sizeof(char));
    while(infix[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("Into the loop");
        if(isOperand(infix[i]))
        {
            postfix[j++]=infix[i];
          
        }
        else if(infix[i]==')')
        {
            while((x=pop(&s)) != '(')
            {
             
                postfix[j++]=x;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(s.top==1)
                {
                
                push(&s,infix[i]);
                }
            else
            {
                while(!(s.top=1) && inStckPri(s.A[s.top])>=inComePri(infix[i]))
                {
                    postfix[j++]=pop(&s);
                    
                }
                push(&s,infix[i]);
            }
        }
        i++;
            }
    while(!(s.top==1))
    {
        
        postfix[j++]=pop(&s);
    }
    postfix[j]='\0';
    printf("the postfix expression is %s",postfix);


}


int main()
{   
    char infix[50];

    printf("Enter the infix expression \n");
    gets(infix);

    
    convert(infix);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1 - `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1; 2 - never use `gets` - it doesn't check for buffer overflow; 3 - put a default in your `switch` statements (didn't your compiler warn about this?); 4 - work out *where* your program stops and ask again

Comment: Forget about the infix/postfix part for now and start fixing the stack data structure. How are you compiling this program? it is [not](https://godbolt.org/z/cWeae5) standard C. Even if it was, it sets `top = 1`, while the first index of an array is 0, it pushes data in that index and increment `top`, but then it pops the element at `top`, which is undeterminate.